# UINavigationController custom titleView

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation controller with a root view controller for which i have the customised titleView instead of normal title for the navigation item.

If i pushed a new controller in it , the default back button title is "back", Since i have used custome titleView.

I want it to be different. I tried by setting the title in backbaritem of the root view controller, but no use.

I can create a bar button item in my pushed controller and i can set it as leftbar item, But i want it like a normal back button. [Pointing towards backward]

1. Is it possible to set title for the back button , if i have a custom titleView ?
2. Is it possible to create a bar button item as like as default back button.[Pointing towards back , other than plain,border...etc] ?

Regards,
Balaji R.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Even though i have custom titleView for my navigation item, I can still set the title for the same navigation item where it wont be taken for the title display in navigation item . but it will taken as the title of the back button when some other controllers are pushed into it.

So , Now i'm having both title [Used for back title display] and titleView [custom view] in the navigation item.

Thanks,
Balaji R.